# Setting to-one relationship value in Core data get unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have 2 entities(A, B) in my model. 
They have such reverse to-one relationship: A<---->B.

Here is how I add new record into core data:

`NSManagedObject *moA = NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"A" 
                inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`

`NSManagedObject *moB = NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"B" 
                inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`

```
[moA setValue:@"http://www.apple.com" forKey:@"url"];
[moB setValue:@"Apple inc." forKey:@"title"];
```

`// set reverse relationship`

`[moA setValue:moB forKey:'relationToB'];`

`[moB setValue:moA forKey:'relationToA'];`

After I run this code, I get error:

**unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
[moA setValue:moB forKey:'relationToB'];
```

... should be:

```
[moA setValue:moB forKey:@"relationToB"];
```

In the original, you are attempting to pass a C string literal as the key instead of an NSString object. In key-value coding, the name of the key is converted into a method name (a selector) e.g. `@"relationToB"` gets converted to a selector of `setRelationToB:`

However, the C string literal is not an object but just an address for a memory range which converts into a gibberish selector name producing the error.